# DefinitelyTyped files reference through CDN to use it in Angular2?

Tags: angular, definitelytyped

I'm unaware with `GITHUB` process/flow/functionalities.

What if I'm not using NPM or I don't want to download `jquery.d.ts`  file to my local project directory. Rather, I just want to use online repo directly through ***CDN*** or something.

Is there a way to use it directly rather than downloading?

If possible can you give me a little demo on jquery at `Plunkr` please?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vY9EoUDxsBKV5EaNFNm4?p=preview look at this for cdn of jQeury, if you want something more as answer tell me ill post it.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/JTILoHXHBSspJe8bEJBB?p=preview look at here and help me. How to use jquery with it?